# How to add an IMAP/POP3 account programmatically

Tags: android, accounts

I'm writing an app to  add an IMAP/POP3 account programmatically. The problem is, I can't get it displayed in the  Accounts&Sync Settings.

```
   Account account = new Account(context);
   account.se;
   account.setDescription("acc added thr prog"); 
   account.setAutomaticCheckIntervalMinutes(10);
   account.setEmail("UserName@gmail.com");
   account.setDraftsFolderName("Drafts");
   account.setOutboxFolderName("OutBox");
   account.setSentFolderName("Sent");
   account.setTrashFolderName("Trash");
   account.setName("Tester");
   account.setNotifyNewMail(true);
   account.setSenderUri(mContext,"smtp+ssl+://UserName%40gmail.com:Password@smtp.gmail.com");
   mAccount.setStoreUri(mContext,"imap+ssl+://UserName%40gmail.com:Password@imap.gmail.com");
   account.setDeletePolicy(10); 
   account.setVibrate(true);
   mPrefer = Preferences.getPreferences(getInstrumentation().getContext()); 
   account.save(mPrefer);
   Object mInstrumenatation;
   Email.setServicesEnabled(mInstrumenatation.getTargetContext());
```

Thanks.